# javascript Callback function fail

Tags: javascript

So I am having a code which using callback due to async script,, and now when I try it, i got lost can somebody help me how to fix my code? this script was to check if a picture dimension was less than 300x300 or not

```
function validate_dimention(fileName, callback){
            input = document.getElementById("profilepic");
            file = input.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var image  = new Image();
            var width;
            var height;
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload() = function(pic) {
                image.src    = pic.target.result;              // url.createObjectURL(file);
                image.onload = function() {
                    width = this.width;
                    height = this.height;
                    if (width <= 300 && height <= 300) {
                        callback(true);
                    } else {
                        callback(false);
                    }
                };
            };
        }

        validate_dimention(fileName, function (result) {
            return function (result);
        });
```

Comment: First of all you should remove the parentheses after the `reader.onload`.

What's the purpose of the callback?In this cae there's no point in returning anything in the callback.

Comment: Are you getting errors when trying to run it or does it just produce the wrong result? Also, When you call `validate_dimention` at the bottom, I think you should just `return result;`. `return function (result);` is not valid js syntax.

Comment: Also `input, file` don't appear to be defined. Are these defined at a higher level? If so this could cause issues if this runs multiple times in parallel. What is the error it gives? If you haven't already open the dev tools and see if exceptions are thrown.